Removing Salt and Pepper Noise from Images Using OpenCV
I've been trying to remove the noise from the following image which contains a QR code:

I've attempted to remove noise from the image using linear filtering techniques such as Gaussian blur and median filtering. However, while these methods successfully reduced noise, they also significantly blurred the QR code, making it difficult to scan accurately. I was expecting the noise to be reduced while preserving the sharpness and clarity of the QR code. Which algorithm or technique should I use to effectively remove noise from the image while preserving the details of the QR code?

Well, that is what linear filters do.
But since you know this is a QR-code, why having a grayscale image, and not a binary one?
If you blur the image, you transform a bunch of pixels into a continuous gray information, that goes from 0 to 1, depending on how much black or white pixels are around. Good. That is a good first step for a simple algorithm.
But then, the objective is to see that level as a sort of level of probability for a pixel to be black. You know that nothing is gray in your image. It is either white or black. So, use a threshold. And however continuous are the transition between black and white in your now blurry image, it has to have an edge, at which pixels go from "more black than white" to "more white than black".
And then, from the now binary image, you can use some morphological operator to filter some remaining noise
I get some acceptable result (that my phone sees instantly as "mal7 w felfel") with a heavy gaussian blur, then threshold, then closing and opening.
cv2.morphologyEx(cv2.morphologyEx(((cv2.blur(img, (19,19))[...,0]>126)*255).astype(np.uint8), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel), cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
with kernel=np.ones((17,17), dtype=np.uint8)
I am sure those parameters could be tuned a bit. I didn't. Point is, you know that your final result is a binary image, so do the bluring only as a preliminary step to try to guess where is black and where is white.
Of course, there exist some more complicated algorithm to sharpen edegs.
And even more, if you know that it is a QR-code (or simply a grid of some sort), that you are looking at, then you could try some ad-hoc algorithm, inferring where are the lines of the grid, and what is the color of each cell of the grid. But that would be outside the scope of an answer on a forum.


The general way
My algorithm of choice for this task would be Total Variance Denoising.
It is a kind of edge-preserving low-pass filter.  Here is an example image of it in 1D.

The wikipedia page for it explains it well, I won't copy the contents here.
You can search Github for implementations of this algorithm in your preferred programming language.
The drawback is that it requires solving a fused-lasso minimization problem, which in your case, for a 1012x1012 image, is an optimization over ~1 million parameters.
The quick and dirty way
Following chrslg's suggestion, if you know a-priori certain properties of your image, you can leverage that for quick results. For example, your QR code seems to be a 1012x1012 image with 23x23 cells that are 44 pixels wide.
So you could do something like:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frame = Image.open('/home/skootenbeeten/wis8wemY.png')
image = np.array(frame)[..., 0]

estimate = np.zeros_like(image)
cell_width = 44
magic_number = 130 # histogram the mean of all cells and look for a break

for n in np.arange(23):
    for m in np.arange(23):
        ii = cell_width*n
        jj = cell_width*m
        if np.mean(image[ii:ii+cell_width, jj:jj+cell_width]) < magic_number:
            estimate[ii:ii+cell_width, jj:jj+cell_width] = 0.0
        else:
            estimate[ii:ii+cell_width, jj:jj+cell_width] = 1.0
       
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2, dpi=120)
axarr[1].imshow(estimate, cmap='gray', extent=[0, 1012, 0, 1012])

axarr[0].imshow(image[:, :], cmap='gray', extent=[0, 1012, 0, 1012])
axarr[0].vlines(np.arange(23)*cell_width, 0, 1012, color='r', lw=1)
axarr[0].hlines(np.arange(23)*cell_width, 0, 1012, color='r', lw=1)

Note the magic number: I chose it by histogramming the mean of all cells and picking a value inbetween the two peaks of the bimodal distribution.

